# how to do multiple calculations using ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a simple Countries table with name, continent, population and some other fields.

i'm trying to perform the following MySQL query using ActiveRecord

**SELECT count(*), SUM(population), AVG(population) FROM countries where continent='Asia'**

how should I go about it?

i've tried:

Country.where(:continent => 'Asia').count()

Country.where(:continent => 'Asia').sum(:population)

Country.where(:continent => 'Asia').average(:population)

all work great individually, they all return numbers (not an ActiveRelation object), which means you can't do something like

Country.where(:continent => 'Asia').count().sum(:population).average(:population)

Comment: You realy want to receive Countries, that are simultaneously counted, grouped and averaged? :)

Comment: @lol007, I want to find the number of countries in asia, the total population of asia, and the average population of countries in asia

Answer (score 4):

found the solution:

result = Country.select("count(*) as num_countries, sum(population) as total_population, avg(population) as average_population).where(:continent => 'asia').to_a[0]

which allows you to then access the results like so:
result.num_countries, result.total_population and result.average_population

Answer (score 0):

You can try sth like:

```
ActiveRecord::base.connection.execute('SELECT count(*), SUM(population), AVG(population) FROM countries where continent='Asia')
```

This will return a hash:

```
{'count(*)': count, ... }
```

Comment: thanks dude, but I was looking for a way to do it following the Rails 3 activerecord syntax.  Found it.